# How to create a custom Vsync rules for 'Compton'?

Tags: compton

I use [Compton](https://github.com/chjj/compton) to force Vsync. Can anyone tell me how I can disable Vsync for certain applications to avoid the input lag? I probably only want to do this for *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive* and creating rules for other applications is easy after seeing an example. CS:GO's process name is **csgo_linux**.
My *compton.conf*:

```
backend = "glx";  
paint-on-overlay = true;  
glx-no-stencil = true;  
glx-no-rebind-pixmap = true;  
vsync = "opengl-swc";
```

---

I have disabled shadows for some programs using:

```
shadow-exclude = [  
 "! name~=''",  
 "n:e:Notification",  
 "n:e:Plank",  
 "n:e:Docky",  
 "g:e:Synapse",  
 "g:e:Kupfer",  
 "g:e:Conky",  
 "n:w:*Firefox*",  
];
```

Should be possible also for Vsync.